# ¿Qué significa : "Anota en el texto una palabra oxítona con acento escrito, y otra palabra oxítona sin acento escrito"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

*Forenote: I'm not asking anyone to do my homework. I post this here since I reckon that my misunderstandment of the question may stem from a lack of understandment of spanish langauge subtilities in the question.*

Hola, maestros y hermanos,

Tengo que hacer un trabajo importante, y me ha llamado la atención este requisito:

> Anota en el texto una palabra **oxítona** con acento escrito, y otra
>   palabra oxítona sin acento escrito.

Cuando dice "palabra oxítona con acento escrito", ¿estamos hablando efectivamente de palabras como "´**con'ver'sa'ción**", en las cuales el acento sirve para trasladar la letra tónica? ¿O, por el contrario, hablamos de palabras como "**ahí** ", donde en ambos casos (sin tilde/con tilde), la letra tónica es la  "i"?

Este es el texto completo :

> Cada vez que se veían, que poco a poco era cada vez más a menudo,
>   Carmen le preguntaba cómo iba el divorcio. Y él decía bien, **ahí**
>   anda, como si se tratara de un grano o un reúma crónico, e intentaba
>   cambiar el tema de **conversación**. Tenía la sensación de que si le
>   contaba a Carmen la verdad, que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo
>   de divorciarse sino de separarse, Carmen se evaporaría, desaparecería,
>   y la sola idea le ponía enfermo. No es que estuviera enamorado de
>   ella, sino que no podía concebir levantarse por las mañanas y no
>   pensar en que la vería a la hora de comer o que pasarían la tarde
>   juntos. Ella también tenía compromisos y ocupaciones, pero siempre se
>   las arreglaban para verse un ratito. Se llamaban por teléfono a diario
>   y comentaban cosas de sus trabajos o cosas que habían sucedido y que
>   habían salido en el periódico o en los telediarios. Álvaro nunca había
>   tenido una relación tan cómplice con una mujer, con la que además se
>   acostaba. Había leído en las novelas que estas relaciones a veces se
>   daban entre hombres y mujeres, pero a él nunca le había pasado. Y era
>   esta sensación de que Carmen y él eran además amigos y cómplices en la
>   vida, lo que le perdió.**

Dudo que la cuestión sea una trampa, y por eso quería tener su opinión

Saludos.

PS: Por favor, disculpen mi español de baja calidad, estoy aprendiendo vuestra lengua y no sé aún escribir como un nativo :-)

Comment: Hola, Mintou! He modificado ligeramente tu texto para hacerlo más idiomático. Me gustaría destacarte los siguientes cambios. Primero, he cambiado "instrucción" por "apartado". Normalmente una "instrucción" define una serie de pasos concretos que hay que llevar a cabo para completar una tarea. Pero dichos pasos no contienen preguntas a completar. Por darte un ejemplo, puedes fijarte en las instrucciones de montaje que acompañan los muebles de IKEA.

Comment: Por otro lado, "palabra" y "letra" son de género femenino en español, por tanto los determinantes y adjetivos que las acompañan deben concordar con ellas: las cuales, la tercera i. Por último, he quitado justamente eso de "la tercera i". Al ponerlo suponemos que en la palabra hay tres i'es - primera, segunda y tercera - cuando solo hay una que ocupa la tercera posición. Dado que no hay más i'es en "ahí", sobra aclarar su posición. Cualquier duda que tengas sobre mis cambios, poniendo @rubioric al comenzar un comentario, me saldrá un aviso e intentaré responderte.

Comment: And last but not least, he cambiado "respectos" por "saludos". "Respectos" no se emplea para despedir un mensaje o comunicado y además no suele tener plural, ya que normalmente forma parte de una locución adverbial o preposicional.

Comment: Mil gracias por las correcctiones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el DRAE

> **oxítona**
>   [palabra] Que lleva el acento prosódico en la última sílaba.
>
> [**acento prosódico**](https://dle.rae.es/acento#6PLVzjM)
>   1. m. acento (‖ relieve en la pronunciación).
>
> **[tilde](https://dle.rae.es/tilde?m=form)**
>   1. f. acento (‖ signo ortográfico español)

Palabras como *adiós*, *tomar* o *salí* son oxítonas, llevan el **acento prosódico**, de voz, en la última sílaba. Solo adiós y salí llevan **acento ortográfico** o **tilde**.

En español llevan **tilde** las palabras oxítonas que terminan en vocal o en las consonantes **n** o **s**.

**conversación** y **ahí** son las dos oxítonas y llevan tilde. No entiendo en qué diferencias una de otra en relación a ambos tipos de acento.

Quizás la tilde es más difícil de ver en la letra i, pero en **ahí** lo lleva.

Comment: Si, tiene razón, no hay diferencia entre ahí y conversación en este sentido. La siguiente pregunta era "anota en el texto una palabra paroxítona con acento escrito" y tenía dudas  para saber si podía incluir palabras con accento gramatical como "sólo", o si se trataba unicamente de palabras con tilde prosódico. Gracias por la respuesta, me ayuda un montón.

Answer (score -2):

*Ahí* seria una palabra oxítona con tilde y *conversación* es una palabra oxítona sin tilde

oxitona con tilde se refiere a las palabras que acentuadas en la ultima silaba terminan en "n" o "s" las otras oxitonas son sin tilde

Comment: "murcielago, "Ahí seria una palabra oxítona con tilde y conversación es una palabra oxítona con tilde" ?  Quierría decir : "Ahí seria una palabra oxítona *sin* tilde y conversación es una palabra oxítona con tilde" ?